# Find which parameters a higher order function contains

Tags: javascript

I have a function that accepts a function as an argument.
This callback function can receive up to 5 parameters. Any of these can be null at some point.

I tried accessing the arguments property, but it throws this error:
**'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode.**

Is it possible to find which arguments this function received? So i don't have to pass it all 5 each time?

```
function bar(callback){
  // do some stuff
  return callback(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
}
```

Some use cases I'm having:

```
bar((a, b, c) => a + c)
bar((a, b, c, d) => a + c + d)
bar((a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + e)
```

I'm always calling the callback with 5 arguments, but sometimes, not all of them are being used. And for each one, I'm doing some computation.

Another example:

If I call the function like this:

```
bar((a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + e)
```

And my function defined like this:

```
function bar(callback){
  // do some stuff with
  return callback(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
}
```

There would be no need for me to pass the third and fourth parameters to the callback, because they are null. But since I don't have access to the arguments the callback has received, I'm not being able to do this.

Comment: why not simply pass values as an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length),

```
function func1() {}

function func2(a, b) {}

console.log(func1.length);
// expected output: 0

console.log(func2.length);
// expected output: 2
```

But, I would not advice writing code that relies on this. The callback function could be implemented in different ways that this wouldn't work. Some examples:

```
function callback(){
    console.log(arguments); // could access all parameters but length is 0
}

function callback(...args){
    console.log(args); // could access all parameters but length is 0
}

function callback(a,b=0,c,d,e){
     console.log(a,b,c,d,e); // could access all parameters but length is 1
    // 1, only parameters before the first one with 
    // a default value is counted
}
```

A better solution would be not overloading the function with different behaviors depending on what the callback expects, and actually tell what you should "return" to the callback

```
function bar(callback, n){
    if(n===0) // do something
    else if(n===1) // do something else
}
```

Or don't write "overloaded" functions that have multiple behaviors, and actually having multiple functions:

```
function foo(callback){
  // do some sutff
  return callback(first, second)
}

function bar(callback){
  // do some sutff
  return callback(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
}
```

---

EDIT: from your last edit you should need to have something like this

```js
function bar(params, callback) {
  const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5
  };

  const args = params.map(p => obj[p]);
  return callback.apply(this, args);
}

console.log(bar(['a', 'b'], (a, b) => a + b)) //3
console.log(bar(['a', 'd', 'e'], (a, d, e) => a + d + e)) //10
```

Comment: Yeah. I think its more worth it to just make other functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the [`Function#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of the function, which returns the number of defined parameters.

```js
function bar(callback) {
    console.log(callback.length);
}

bar((a, b) => a + b);
bar(function (a, b, c) { console.log(a, b, c); });
```

Comment: I edited the question. I think I didn't explain it well.

Comment: what has changed?

Comment: The issue is not the length of the arguments, it's the order that they are. For instance, you passed 5 arguments (a, b, c, d, e), but I might not need b and d.

Comment: then i don't understand *"So i don't have to pass it all 5 each time?"*. you need at least the number of paramter which you use. mabe a wrapper function or a property (needs to be implemented) of the function has this information.

Comment: @Glund That's still not what you are asking in your question. This answer is still correct for the updated question

Comment: I asked if it was possible to find which arguments were given to the function, not how many